# How to get exact X and Y origin values of pdf page in iOS, PDFKit, swift

Tags: ios, position, pdfkit, pdfpage

I'm using PDFKit to display pdf using pdfview to user and it works perfectly. here is my implementation of pdfview. and here are the properties of pdfview.

```
if let pdfdoc = PDFDocument(url: docurl) {
    print("working")
    pdfdocument = pdfdoc
    pdfview.document = pdfdocument
    pdfview.autoScales = false
    pdfview.delegate = self
    pdfview.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
}
```

now what I want is to get exact origin of the current page. but it gives always (0,1) for each and every page. this is how I tried.

```
let currentpage = pdfview.currentPage
print(currentpage?.bounds(for: .mediaBox).origin.x)
```

the `X` value is always `0`.

I have attached a screenshot which I want to get the x and y value of the page.

[image]

How can I get this x and y value of the pdf page. hope your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following:

```
const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument({
  size: [
    pageParameters.width,
    pageParameters.height
  ],
  margins: {
    printing: 'highResolution',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  }
})
```